# A way to copy files from one Caprover image to another

Tags: django, docker, nginx, media, caprover

I uploaded a website using caprover and django and works well. Everything works fine, but I noticed whenever I updated the project user files get lost, although everything gets updated quite well. I understand caprover is build on top of nginx and docker, but I'm new to them.

Every time I update caprover it builds a new image( I guess docker image) and this makes user images to disappear (I guess left in the previous image) is there a way to copy those files? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do that is to use a persistant directory as [explain in the doc](https://caprover.com/docs/persistent-apps.html).

You need to create an app with persistant data then tell CapRover with path on your container will be mounted to a host path.

After that the user files will be stored on the host (not on the container) so when CapRover build a new Docker image with your new version it will remplace the container but it will mount the host path so the images will still be there.

Comment: Thanks so much. It really gave me a headache, and I wasn't sure anyone will answer.